# Calculating Poisson CDF

Tags: poisson-distribution

I have a quite basic question about Poisson CDF. I have the following function $P(x;\mu)$ referring to the Poisson CDF.

Hadley and Whitin (1963) defined the Poisson density as

$p(x;\mu)= \frac{\mu^x}{x!}e^{-\mu}$

and complementary cumulative distribution function as

$P(x;\mu)=\sum_{j=x}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^j}{j!}e^{-\mu}$.

**To calculate $P(x;\mu)$, can I use the following:**

**$P(x;\mu)=1-\sum_{j=0}^{x-1}\frac{\mu^j}{j!}e^{-\mu}$**

**knowing that**

**$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^j}{j!}e^{-\mu}=1$?**

I have seen several applications of CDF calculation online and they made me confused. Can you help to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply sum the probabilities up to $P(X=x-1)$ and subtract it from $1$, to obtain $P(X \geq x)$ which is correct. However, CDF normally is defined as $P(X\leq x)$, however note that, in your book (or post), it is defined as $P(X\geq x)$. Check the definition out from [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Poisson_distribution). Your book may be consistent about its definition, which is perfectly OK if you stay *within* the book, but trying to compare what you do in your exercises and the outside world, you may find little discrepancies.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening explanation. I realized that I misquoted Hadley and Whitin (1963). They defined the complementary CDF as what I have given. So, I will correct my post. But, it was good to learn what I was doing was correct.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Sometimes unexplained downvotes just show up.  There have been a bunch lately.  When you're confident your post is clear, correct, addresses the original question, and has no obvious need of improvement, perhaps the best interpretation is that the downvoter is confused--which doesn't reflect on you. (+1, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

A *cumulative distribution function* is defined as $$F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x)$$or more rarely as$$F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X< x)$$in older (e.g., French or Hungarian) texts, but never as the complement$$F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\ge x)$$which is [the *complementary cumulative distribution* or the *tail distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_(tail_distribution)).

Comment: I agree with you. I have just misquoted. I will correct my post.

Comment: @user8028576:thanks,  deleting the question altogether would be better imho as it does not contain aspects that I feel are useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to calculate the Poisson CDF is to use its mathematical correspondence with the Chi-square distribution. Let $X \sim Poisson(\mu)$. Then $P(X \leq x_0) = P(Y > 2\mu)$ where $Y \sim \chi^2_{2(x_0+1)}$.

For example, in R both of the following equal .61596.

```
ppois(5,5)

1-pchisq(10,12)
```